# Blue Prism : Need help to update a collection

Tags: blueprism

This has been driving me nuts for ages now and I know it might seem really basic but I don't remember it ever being covered in the training course I'm taking. Basically I have built a process that logs in to an order system, gets items from a work queue, places an order and then captures the reference number.

The reference number I am sending back from the `capture reference` Business Object to the Process but I am stumped as to how to add this data to my existing collection as the column name does not exist. 
I keep getting the error

> Field Data.reference-number not found

and I know this is because it doesn't exist in the Current Values tab in the collection.

The best I can do is store this returning data into a separate data object in order to not disrupt the process but this doesn't really help me as I need to be able to view the reference number in the control room via the data logs of the work queue.

Can anybody help me append this returning data to my existing collection? Would really appreciate the advice. Thanks

Comment: To get attention to your question, and possibly an answer, you should make an effort to make it more readable. A single long paragraph is not so inviting... break it up, add some line breaks!

Answer (score 2):

You can check the column existence in collection by using VBO `Utility - Collection Manipulation` and action `Collection contains Field`. If results `False`, you can append the field by using action `Append Field (Text)`. It will return you the `Collection` with appended column. Below is snippet for a reference:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vijay. I think I can see the problem I have now and it's that I do not have access to VBO - Utility Collection Manipulation at all.

Comment: @MartinThompson If you don't have an access over VBO `Utility - Collection Manipulation`, you can create that action using  `Code Stage` which will give you `Collection` with appended column.

Comment: Why not just import Utility - Collection Manipulation?

Comment: I'm in a training environment and can't import anything.

Answer (score 2):

The way you can deal with it is by checking your collection if the **Reference Column** exists via **Action Field Exists**:

1. If it does then just add the **Order Reference Number** via **Calculation stage** to the collection field and update your Item in work Queue via **Action Set Data**
2. If it does not then use **Action Append Field (Text)** and add the field  **Order Reference Number** to your collection and then update your Item in work Queue via **Action Set Data**

Visually it would look like the image below:

[image]

Hope these information will help you.

Comment: Thanks Konstantinos. I will have a go at this but if the 'Action Append Field (Text) part requires me to have access to VBO - Utility Collection Manipulation then as with Vijay's reply below it seems I won't be able to complete this task.

Comment: @MartinThompson - why not just import Utility - Collection Manipulation?